# Searching for a Vampire Knight Fanfiction!

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, vampire-knight

I read that fanfiction years ago on fanfiction.net. (Kaname xZero)

The council visits the academy and cross says to yuki that she should take care of zero because he is only an ex-human. 
Yuki runs into a member of the council and gets bitten. Zero saves her but gets raped and bitten. Yuki runs to Kaname for help.

Thats all I know.

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: One of these; https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=inurl%3Afanfiction.net+"take+care+of+zero"&o